# Java server listen to socket when needed

Tags: java, sockets, client, listen

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server(9008);
    }
}

public class Server {

    private ServerSocket server;
    private Socket client;

    public Server(int port) {
        try {
            // Create out server with our desired port
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            // Server started, let the user know
            System.out.println("Server started at port " + port + "...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Unable to start server, print error
            System.out.println("Unable to start server on port " + port + "...");
        } 
        // Start our main server method
        runServer();
    }

    public void runServer() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Wait for new clients and accept them
                client = server.accept();
                // Let the user know - print
                System.out.println("New user connected - " + client.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress());
                // Start thread for our client
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ClientConnection(client));
                clientThread.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So at this points everything is going fine, now inside my clientThread the problem starts

```
    public class ClientConnection implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;

    public ClientConnection(Socket client) {
        // Set client socket
        this.socket = client;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            // Read from our client input
            BufferedReader readClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = readClient.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Client says - " + readClient.readLine());
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

My actual client

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9008);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            writer.write("Hello\n");
            writer.flush();
            socket.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I will get "Client says - null" displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: The way to read in an InputStream/Reader is somethink like

```
while ((myString = readClient.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(myString);
}
```

this way the loop will exit when the connection is closed.

Also, move the `try/catch` outside the loop, or do some error control. If you get an exception, you do not want to just try get again in the loop.

UPDATE2: In case my comment was not clear enough, over your updated code do

```
        String line;
        while ((line = readClient.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Client says - " + line);
        }
```

Just one read per iteration, at the `while`, so the loop can exit if `line` is `null` (that means the connection has been closed).

Comment: I will make the client send output each time a key is pressed, if I remove the loop will the thread still read that client output? (at the same connecction, not new)

Comment: My bad, I thought you were reading before the while. Don't make the `while (true)`, but `while (readLine!= null)` (you will need to add a variable inside to catch the value, too.

Comment: Oh, is that the best way to handle this?

Comment: Updated with new code, now Im getting Client says - null

Comment: That is a more logical behavior. You get that because you call `readLine` twice, and the second one is `null` because the connection has been closed. In the print, you should use the `line` variable (you only call `readLine` in the `while`, store it in `line` and check if it is `null` at the same time).